# How to assign value to a global variable inside a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

```
var cachekey = null;

function redis_post(req, res, next) {
    client.get(keyName, (err, redis_data) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        else if (!redis_data) {
            client.set(keyName, JSON.stringify(key));
            cachekey = JSON.parse(redis_data);
        } else if (redis_data) {
            cachekey = JSON.parse(redis_data);
        }
        // next()
    })
    // console.log("check"+cachekey) // undefined
}
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.API_BASE_URL,
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': cachekey // undefined
    },
    credentials: true
});
```

the problem was simple async await query, I just put async before redis_post func and await before client.get(key....)

Comment: **IF** `redis_post` / `client.get` is being called, this should work as expected. I don't think that this problem has to do with hoisting.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with hoisting. It's about the order of execution with asynchronous callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing some async code and depnding on it you assign a value. Console.log is called before you got the response fom the async function.

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) in the comment section from jabaa refers to this problem.

Answer (score -1):

We use Interceptors in axios instance maybe it solve your problem

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.API_BASE_URL,
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': cachekey // undefined
    },
    credentials: true
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    config.headers.Authorization =  cachekey;
    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```